# Solr use with Mysql. Searching multiple tables at once

Tags: mysql, solr

I would like to use Solr with MySQL. Does Solr work with MySQL ?

I will have several sections on my site. My website would be written in PHP and MySQL. The various sections are: forums, notes, discussions, etc.

Can it be used to search across all the tables/repositories at once?

Can it link back to the main record when a user searches on particular search result ?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to use Solr with MySQL. Does Solr work with MySQL?

Yes. Solr is not specific to any storage mechanism. You have to tell it what to index.

> Can it be used to search across all the tables/repositories at once?

Yes. It's entirely up to you how your data is indexed and searched on.

> Can it link back to the main record when a user searches on particular search result?

Yes. You just need to store references in the index that can associate back to your data, like a unique id.

Comment: Notably, you can also search multiple tables with plain mysql.  Not sure why that is a question.